# Is this a 仮定形 (kateikei) form, and how to analyse it?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, syntax, renyōkei

I'm stuck with the word **かけ** in the following text below (towards the beginning of Japanese tale, *Kachikachi yama*).

Obviously, "(こしを)かけ" stands for "(腰を)掛ける" (to sit down). But what's the grammar behind 掛け ? Is it a 仮定形 (kateikei) ? I don't understand what's the grammatical construction. Any help would be appreciated !

---

An old man wants to catch a mischievous tanuki, and ...

> そこで、 つぎ の 日、 たぬき の すわって いた きりかぶ に とりもち を べっとり ぬりつけて おきました。 おじいさん が まめ を まいて いたら たぬき が やって きて、 きりかぶ に こし を **かけ**、 せん つぶ まいたら ひと つぶ に なあれ ひと つぶ まいたら くさって しまえ と からかい だしました。

Translation from Tom Ray and Sachiko Matsubara, which was available during some years [here](http://www.his.atr.jp/~ray/stories/kachikachiyama.html).

> Then, the next day, the tree stump where the raccoon had been sitting, had been prepared with a lot of tanglefoot. While the old man was sowing beans the raccoon approached, and sat on the tree stump : "if you sow a thousand seeds they become one seed, if you sow one seed it will completely rot", he begain to tease.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%E4%B8%AD%E6%AD%A2%E5%BD%A2%22

Comment: Other related posts: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E9%80%A3%E7%94%A8%E4%B8%AD%E6%AD%A2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's a *ren’yōkei* 連用形。 A *ren’yōkei* mid-sentence is for coordination, like English “he sat, **and**…”.  You can think of it as a literary equivalent of 「こしをかけて、。。。」

*Kateikei* is what comes before *-ba*, so in this case it would be *kake**re**-*.  Full table, with sample context:

- 未然形： 掛け-　 *kake-* *(-nai)*
- 連用形： 掛け-　 *kake-* *(-masu)*
- 終止形： 掛ける　*kake-ru* *(yo.)*
- 連体形： 掛ける-　*kake-ru-* *(hito)*
- 仮定形： 掛けれ-　*kake-re-* *(-ba)*
- 命令形： 掛けろ／掛けよ　*kake-ro/kake-yo* *(!)*

This is because 掛ける *kakeru* is a vowel-stem *(ichidan)* verb.  Perhaps you were thinking of consonant-stem *(godan)* vebs, such as 書く *kaku*.  These have different vowels depending on the inflection:

- 未然形： 書か-　 *kak-a-* *(-nai)*
- 連用形： 書き-　 *kak-i-* *(-masu)*
- 終止形： 書く  　*kak-u* *(yo.)*
- 連体形： 書く- 　*kak-u-* *(hito)*
- 仮定形： 書け-　*kak-e-* *(-ba)*
- 命令形： 書け  　*kak-e* *(!)*

Notice the difference between 「書けば」 and 「掛け**れ**ば」。

Comment: Thank you very much : all these details are so usefull to know !